# При передаче RECORD в качестве параметра ошибка: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'F'?

Tags: oracle, plsql, типы-данных

Есть такой код:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_test IS
    TYPE trec is RECORD(c1 number);
    FUNCTION f (r trec) RETURN VARCHAR2;
END pkg_test;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_test IS 
    FUNCTION f (r trec) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS 
    BEGIN
        RETURN 'a';
    END f;
END pkg_test;
/
DECLARE
    TYPE trec IS RECORD (c1 NUMBER);
    rec trec;  
    var VARCHAR2(15);
BEGIN
    rec.c1 := 1;
    var := pkg_test.f (rec);
END;
/
```

При выполнении анонимного блока получаю эту ошибку:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'F'

Почему так, ведь типы записей полностью идентичны?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [what is wrong passing a record type as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67197001) от участника [@mikcutu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2362308/mikcutu)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67197001

Answer (score 3):

Тип записи, который объявлен в анонимном блоке (*local type*) и в пакете (*public item*), выглядят одинаково, но PL/SQL это строго типизированный язык, и оба типа записи совершенно независимы и несовместимы. Что по этому поводу говорит [документация](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-7DC81088-1265-4C46-A04D-E3AD10BCC04F):

> A RECORD type defined in a package specification is incompatible with an identically defined local RECORD type.

Надо или напрямую воспользоваться типом из пакета (`r1`), или, если его имя не устраивает, создать локальный подтип записи (`r2`) совместимый с пакетным.

Рабочий пример:

```
declare
    subtype trec is pkg_test.trec;
    r1 pkg_test.trec;  
    r2 trec;  
    var varchar2(15);
begin
    r1.c1 := 1;
    var := pkg_test.f (r1);
    r2.c1 := 1;
    var := pkg_test.f (r2);
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 3):

Начиная с выпуска 18c появился новый тип выражений [*qualified expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/expression.html#GUID-D4700B45-F2C8-443E-AEE7-2BD20FFD45B8__QUALIFIED_EXPRESSION-DEA96F0B).

Попрежнему надо указывать все поля записи, но не надо создавать отдельную переменную только для копирования полей, то есть синтаксис упростился.

Простой пример для наглядности - так надо было раньше:

```
declare
    type trec is record (c1 int, cn int);
    lr trec ;  
    pr pkg_test.trec;  
    ret char (1);
begin
    lr.c1 := 0;
    lr.cn := 1;
    pr.c1 := lr.c1;
    pr.cn := lr.cn;
    ret := pkg_test.f (pr);
end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Так можно теперь:

```
declare
    type trec is record (c1 int, cn int);
    r trec := trec (0,1);  
    ret varchar2(15);
begin
    ret := pkg_test.f (pkg_test.trec (c1=>r.c1, cn=>r.cn));
end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```