# Как реализовать операцию разности коллекций, где значения множеств rowid?

Tags: oracle, plsql, коллекции

Как получить набор значений из первого множества, которых нет во втором?

Первое множество : `l_id_tab`

Второе множество : `RESOLUTION_T`

Ошибка:

> PLS-00306: ошибочно число или типы аргументов при обращении к 'MULTISET_EXCEPT_ALL'

```
declare 
    TYPE RESOLUTION_COLL IS TABLE OF rowid;
    RESOLUTION_T RESOLUTION_COLL:=RESOLUTION_COLL();
    TYPE t_id_tab IS TABLE OF rowid;
    l_id_tab t_id_tab:=t_id_tab();
    TYPE nested_typ IS TABLE OF rowid;
    answer nested_typ; 
begin
    select rowid 
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_id_tab
    from MONITORING;
select s.rowid 
        BULK COLLECT INTO  RESOLUTION_T                  
        from RESEARCH_METRICS_NONAUD_pr ss                          
        join RESEARCH_MEDIA_SOURCE source_dict on source_dict.id=ss.media_id                            
        join RESEARCH_MS_CLIP_DICT cd on cd.media_id=ss.media_id and cd.clip_id=ss.CLIP_ID                          
        join RESEARCH_MS_CLIP_TYPE ct on ct.id=cd.clip_type and ct.media_id=cd.media_id                         
        join research_period pers on pers.prid=ss.period                            
        join MONITORING s on s.action_date=pers.start_date                          
        left join DE_MART.UNICOMPET_MS_CLIP_ATTR_DICT atd on atd.clip_id=cd.clip_id and 
        atd.media_id=cd.media_id and atd.BUSINESS_CATEGORY_ID=21                            
        group by s.rowid;
    answer := l_id_tab MULTISET EXCEPT RESOLUTION_T;
    for iter in answer.first .. answer.last
    loop
    dbms_output.put_line(answer(iter));
    end loop;
end;
```

---

PS похожая ошибка была с методом `exists` коллекции.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все перечисленные в вопросе коллекции: `RESOLUTION_COLL`, `t_id_tab`, `nested_typ`, вроде выглядят одинаково, ведь они содержат элементы с одним и тем же типом данных.

Но это не так, PL/SQL язык строгой типизации, эти коллекции разного типа, их нельзя, ни сравнивать, ни присваивать им результат выражения с коллекциями другого типа.

В ошибке об этом и говорится:

```
declare 
    type ntt1 is table of rowid;
    type ntt2 is table of rowid;
    type ntt3 is table of rowid;
    nt1 ntt1 := ntt1 ();
    nt2 ntt2 := ntt2 ();
    res ntt3; 
begin 
    res := nt1 multiset except nt2;
end;
/
```

> ORA-06550: line 9, column 12:
> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MULTISET_EXCEPT_ALL'

Попробуйте воспользоваться только одним типом, и всё заработает.

Например, так ожидаю одно значение 5 (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1131ab0be54d4c0025e3de549d9880a2)):

```
declare 
    type ntt is table of rowid;
    nt1 ntt := ntt ('1','3','5');
    nt2 ntt := ntt ('1','2','3');
    res ntt; 
begin 
    res := nt1 multiset except nt2;
    dbms_output.put_line ('res.count='||res.count||' res(1)='||res(1));
end;
/

res.count=1 res(1)=5
```

Comment: Я проверил, две коллекции заполнены. Сделал, то что Вы описали. Результат тот же. Изменённый код вставил, в замену старого.

Comment: @максимильин А что вы изменили в коде, или как вы поняли, что надо менять? Насколько вижу отличия выших последних правок, ничего для устранения ошибки не  изменилось.

Comment: @Oxdb, я посмотрел на пример, в примере коллекции однотипны, в своём коде я изменил коллекцию с l_id_tab t_id_tab; на l_id_tab t_id_tab:=t_id_tab(); в две коллекции я передаю rowid, l_id_tab RESOLUTION_T обявлены с rowid

Comment: @максимильин Хорошо, давайте так: как вы поняли фразу _их нельзя, ни сравнивать, ни присваивать им результат выражения с коллекциями другого типа_? У вас три коллекции, все разного типа, а вы пытаетесь их сравнить, а потом ещё присвоить. Если вы не поняли ответ, чуствуйте себя свободно, указать на неточность формулировок, я их изменю.  Добавил в ответ ссылку на фиддле и вы можете там восоздать, что у вас не получается, и опубликовать изменённую ссылку.

Comment: 0xdb, Я не понял Вас. Скажи пожайлуста, почему эти коллекции разного типа ? И как сделать что бы они стали одинаковыми ?

Comment: В ответе же всё написано. Пожалуйста, процитируйте фразу из ответа, которая вам непонятна или вы сомневаетесь, что поняли её правильно.

Comment: _почему эти коллекции разного типа?_, каждое определение - `type type1; type type2` итд, создаёт свой тип, они между собой не совместимы. б) _как сделать что бы они стали одинаковыми_, их одинаковыми сделать нельзя, воспользуйтесь **только одним типом**, каким из трёх не играет никакой роли.

Comment: Заработало благадорю. Каждое определение - type type1; type type2 где это можно прочитать.. Может, я это читал, но не понял это так буквально.

Comment: @максимильин Вот в [этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1277847) более подробно. Там есть ссылка на документацию, но в документации ошибка: там упомянута разница между типами коллекций в пакете и локальными, но две локальные коллекции, как у вас в вопросе, тоже  разные и не совместимы.

Comment: Так как счётчик голосов за ответ не изменился, то по видимому вы не полностью довольны ответом. Дайте предложение по улучшению, мне же тоже интересно развиваться в сторону - донести свои мысли в письменном виде, чтобы было коротко и всем понятно.

Comment: Полностью доволен. Скажи пожайлуста что надо нажать ?

Comment: Увеличьте кол-во значений в коллекции хотя бы до миллиона и замерьте статистику. Есть подозрение, что select ... From table(...) Minus select ... From table(...) Более масштабируемый и менее жаден

Comment: @РавшанАбдулаев А зачем увеличивать кол-во значений в коллекции, и тем более сравнивать их с коллекциями в другом движке? Какой в этом смысл?

Comment: @0xdb, статистика доступна только на [oracle live](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:43:4278105041731::NO:RP::&success_msg=U2NyaXB0ICZxdW90O2NvbXBhcmUgbXVsdGlzZXQgd2l0aCBtaW51cyZxdW90OyB3.,aXRoIDcgc3RhdGVtZW50cyByZXBsYWNlZCB3aXRoIDcgc3RhdGVtZW50cy4~%2FvQRlGbsWnDaILVgb717VEAe-W0PvMApOyLvGqoY6IEVBP8exTz6_7Xw9OXWx8oXLB8XORC7SHYQr6t1ZTBbQDA), но там тоже ограничение по кол-ву записей, что критично решайте сами

Comment: @РавшанАбдулаев Пожалуйста, ответьте на мой предыдущий комментарий. Я не совсем понимаю ваших комментариев. Вы хотите что-то уточнить, или у вас появился новый вопрос?

Comment: @0xdb использование multiset при работе с большими коллекциями не эффективно, это все что я хотел сказать.

Comment: @РавшанАбдулаев Возможно. А какое отношение это имеет к данному вопросу или ответу?